# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined . How do I define it correctly?

Tags: jquery

The following code is in the same php script.  But I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in chrome debugger.

validate.js is in plugins/validate/validate.js

I know this is the problem , as I tried validate.js  when not using  wordpress, by including it externally, & it worked fine. I am using the code below, on  a page.

What is the solutions please?

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_jquery' );
function load_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery');
}


function add_my_css_and_my_js_files() {
    wp_register_script( 'validate', plugins_url( '/validate.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `deps` parameter to include jQuery, change your code to:

```
    function add_my_css_and_my_js_files() {
        wp_register_script( 'validate', plugins_url( '/validate.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script('validate');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files" );
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ' debug error

Comment: Remove the jquery loading portion of your code and then run wp_enqueue_script('validate'); right after the wp_register_script line in @1fixdotio's answer.

Answer (score 0):

uncaught referenceerror jquery is not defined :

error display in console

how can i fix it., help me

```
<script>
function changeval1()
{
    var val = document.getElementById('time').value;
      JQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET", data: {
  zone:val
 },
        url: "fetch.php",             
        dataType: "html",               
        success: function(response){                    
            document.getElementById("times").innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```